# Twitter widget embed

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, twitter, widget

I am using the twitter widget to view my tweets , I would show them horizontally :

TWEET 1 TWEET 2 TWEET 3

I did not see settings in the doc to do this kind of thing.

I use the code of twitter :

```js
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,
            fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);
                                  js.id=id;
                                  js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
                                 }
    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
                            </script>
```

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/XXXXX" data-widget-id="XXXXXXXXX" data-tweet-limit="3" data-chrome="nofooter" width="300" height="500" data-screen-name="XXXXXX">Tweets de @XXXXX</a>
```

1. I use the solution in this WebSite  but doesn't work: [Twitter community](https://twittercommunity.com/t/customize-twitter-embed-widget/36673/6)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter’s widgets JavaScript fires events on initialization and after a viewer interacts with a widget: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events.

You have to load the javascript on the of your page:

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" id="twitter-wjs"></script>
```

Once added the `<script>` tag given by twitter is useless.

Then add some javascript to cutomize the widget once it is rendered.

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind(
    'rendered',
    function (ev) {
      // customization code here
    });
});
```

It is a little bit tedious as the widget appears inside of an `<iframe>` which is out of scope of the css and js of your page. You have to manually add them into the iframe, even if there are already included in your page.
Here is a quick exemple that activates the [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) onto the twitter posts:

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  twttr.events.bind(
    'rendered',
    function (ev) {
      var iframe = ev.target,
          doc = iframe.contentDocument,
          head = doc.querySelector('head'),
          slicklink = document.createElement('link'),
          slickscript = document.createElement('script');

          slicklink.rel = 'stylesheet';
          slicklink.href = '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css';
          head.appendChild(slicklink);

          slickscript.src = '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js';
          head.appendChild(slickscript);
          jQuery(doc.querySelector('ol.h-feed')).slick();
    });
});
```

You the result on the "GET THE DIRECT" section of this [page](http://stylebydeluna.fr/)